# ObjectiveC modal dialog. There is something I am missing with the class interaction

Tags: objective-c

In the following code (from Apple example pages)

```
- (void)showCustomDialog: (NSWindow *)window

// User has asked to see the dialog. Display it.
{
    if (!myCustomDialog)
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed: @"MyCustomDialog" owner: self];



    [NSApp beginSheet: myCustomDialog
        modalForWindow: window
        modalDelegate: nil
        didEndSelector: nil
        contextInfo: nil];

    [NSApp runModalForWindow: myCustomDialog];

    // Dialog is up here.

    [NSApp endSheet: myCustomDialog];

    [myCustomDialog orderOut: self];
}
```

How is the myCustomDialog variable ever set to anything, and when?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingAppModalDialogs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be an outlet in your class, in the nib of the dialogue, file's owner is set to be whatever class you are calling this from, and the outlet is connected to it. When loading the nib with owner self, the outlet is populated.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I had failed to see the link between the code and the objects in IB. Its what comes of only looking at Mac development every 5 years or so, each time its changed again :-)